# Use of BaseController even if all dependencies not used?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have created a base controller with the following constructor:

```
public BaseController(ICustomer customer, ISiteSettings siteSettings, ILogger logger, ILocalizer localizer)
```

All my controllers are using the base as they all use all the dependecies. Now I am creating a new controller `ErrorController` which uses only uses `siteSettings` and not the other dependencies.

I was wondering if it would make sense to not to use the `BaseController` as an inheritance in `ErrorController` and just create a dependency for `SiteSettings`. On the other hand if the using `BaseController` is not too expensive, may be I should just keep the consistency with other controllers?

My feelings are since the dependencies are already registered with `Unity`, hitting the base controller would be a very inexpensive process. Just a thought. Please let me know if you think otherwise.

BaseController Code for your review:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    #region Private Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Factory to obtain customer object
    /// </summary>
    protected readonly ICustomer Customer;

    /// <summary>
    /// Site Settings
    /// </summary>
    protected readonly ISiteSettings SiteSettings;

    /// <summary>
    /// The Localization interface
    /// </summary>
    protected readonly ILocalizer Localizer;

    /// <summary>
    /// The Logger is used for exception handling
    /// </summary>
    protected readonly ILogger Logger;

    #endregion

    #region Ctor

    /// <summary>
    ///     <para>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BaseController"/> class.</para>
    ///     <para>Parameters are injected via Unity.</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="customer">The customer.</param>
    /// <param name="siteSettings">The site settings.</param>
    /// <param name="logger">The logger.</param>
    /// <param name="localizer">The localizer.</param>
    public BaseController(ICustomer customer, ISiteSettings siteSettings, ILogger logger, ILocalizer localizer)
    {
        if (customer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("customer");
        }

        Customer = customer;

        if (siteSettings == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("siteSettings");
        }

        SiteSettings = siteSettings;

        if (logger == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        }

        Logger = logger;

        if (localizer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("localizer");
        }

        Localizer = localizer;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Unless you have some hairy constructors on those dependencies, this should not be an issue.

Comment: so your thoughts is to keep the consistency and use the BaseController?

Comment: I added the baseController Code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have some hairy constructors on those dependencies (not the BaseController constructor itself), this should not be an issue. Your container should handle the grunt work and lifecycle of these. Would use the `BaseController` for consistency and ease of further expansion.

Comment: the code for the constructor is pasted above in the body of question.

Comment: Yea, that constructor is good (simple), I was referring to the various constructors of the dependencies. If your following the same pattern, you should be good!